size of pedersen commitment
May I ask that the parameter requirement of Pedersen commitment?

For $g^{x~modq}h^{r~modq}mod p$, does p depends on q? Or does it only depend on the security parameter desired? How large will the p needs to be given q?
Thanks!


does p depends on q?

Well, yes (actually, I'd phrase it as $q$ depends on $p$, but that's really the same thing).
$q$ needs to be the size of the subgroup generated by $g$ and $h$.  Because of how the math works, that means that $q$ must be a factor of $p-1$.  If it's not, then there will not be a $q$-sized subgroup in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ (and so $g, h$ cannot generate a subgroup of that size).  In that sense, the value that $q$ can be depends on $p$.
Now, these details do change if we do Pedersen commitments in Elliptic Curve groups (because the size of the group is not necessarily $p-1$, but an integer $n$ that is not too far from $p$).  But, the same basic principle will apply.

Thanks, is there any concrete parameters on p? Like given q, p has a lowerbound of f(q)?

@jswang: well, $p$ has to be large enough to resist attacks such as NFS (that is, at least 2048 bits and probably larger).  There's no requirement based on what $q$ is (other than '$q$ must be a factor of $p-1$').  If you have a specific $q$ in mind, then searching for a prime of the form $p = kq + 1$ (for an appropriate sized $k$) works quite well.

@jswang: remember, the only assumptions that Pedersen makes are that finding the discrete log of $h$ w.r.t. $g$ is hard (needed for binding) and that $r$ is selected uniformly from $[0, q)$ (needed for hiding).  Once you satisfy those two assumptions, you're golden
